# TSQL syntax to sum previous n results inside cte

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below does some aggregation based on all records before the current record.

How can amend this to also sum the previous 3 records before the current date?

**Desired Result:**
[image]

[image]

**Current query:**

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '2018-01-01';

with CurrentRows as
(
    select *
    from Control c
    where c.QDate = @Date
)

select cr.*
    , ProductCountArea = sum(case when c.AreaName = cr.AreaName then 1 else 0 end)
    , ProductMatchArea = sum(case when c.Issue = 1 and c.AreaName = cr.AreaName then 1 else 0 end)
    --, Previous3Sum = sum(?) -- <-- New field here?
from CurrentRows cr
join Control c on c.QDate < cr.QDate and c.ProductName = cr.ProductName
group by cr.QDate
    , cr.ProductName
    , cr.AreaName
    , cr.PType
    , cr.Issue
order by cr.AreaName
```

**SQLFiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51dfe/5

**Table Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE Control
    ([QDate] datetime, [ProductName] varchar(10), [AreaName] varchar(10), [PType] int, [Issue] int);

INSERT INTO Control ([QDate], [AreaName], [ProductName], [PType], [Issue])
VALUES
('2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 10, 6),
('2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',' Area5', 'Name2', 9, 2),
('2017-12-15 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 8, 5),
('2017-11-25 00:00:00.000',' Area14', 'Name2', 7, 5),
('2017-11-18 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 10, 2),
('2017-11-13 00:00:00.000',' Area3', 'Name2', 9, 8),
('2017-10-28 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 8, 1),
('2017-10-04 00:00:00.000',' Area2', 'Name1', 7, 2),
('2017-08-26 00:00:00.000',' Area4', 'Name1', 10, 3),
('2017-02-25 00:00:00.000',' Area7', 'Name1', 9, 8),
('2017-02-18 00:00:00.000',' Area12', 'Name1', 8, 5),
('2017-01-25 00:00:00.000',' Area18', 'Name2', 7, 2),
('2017-01-01 00:00:00.000',' Area5', 'Name2', 10, 2),
('2016-12-27 00:00:00.000',' Area7', 'Name1', 9, 1),
('2016-12-09 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 8, 5),
('2016-12-01 00:00:00.000',' Area16', 'Name2', 7, 2),
('2016-11-12 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 10, 1),
('2016-10-27 00:00:00.000',' Area24', 'Name2', 9, 8),
('2016-10-22 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 8, 7),
('2016-09-30 00:00:00.000',' Area13', 'Name2', 7, 2),
('2016-09-24 00:00:00.000',' Area19', 'Name1', 10, 1),
('2016-08-20 00:00:00.000',' Area21', 'Name2', 9, 3),
('2016-07-26 00:00:00.000',' Area21', 'Name2', 8, 1),
('2016-07-17 00:00:00.000',' Area26', 'Name2', 7, 2),
('2016-06-24 00:00:00.000',' Area4', 'Name1', 10, 3),
('2016-06-01 00:00:00.000',' Area4', 'Name1', 9, 2),
('2016-05-29 00:00:00.000',' Area15', 'Name2', 8, 8),
('2016-05-10 00:00:00.000',' Area25', 'Name1', 7, 3),
('2016-05-05 00:00:00.000',' Area31', 'Name2', 10, 1),
('2016-04-13 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 9, 2),
('2016-04-03 00:00:00.000',' Area3', 'Name2', 8, 7),
('2016-03-09 00:00:00.000',' Area5', 'Name2', 7, 3),
('2016-02-27 00:00:00.000',' Area7', 'Name1', 10, 10),
('2016-02-06 00:00:00.000',' Area23', 'Name1', 9, 1),
('2016-01-01 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 8, 3),
('2015-12-08 00:00:00.000',' Area28', 'Name1', 7, 4),
('2015-11-10 00:00:00.000',' Area17', 'Name1', 10, 3),
('2015-05-17 00:00:00.000',' Area19', 'Name2', 9, 7),
('2015-04-24 00:00:00.000',' Area7', 'Name1', 8, 1),
('2015-04-21 00:00:00.000',' Area18', 'Name2', 7, 3),
('2015-04-07 00:00:00.000',' Area9', 'Name1', 10, 8),
('2015-03-11 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 9, 10),
('2015-02-27 00:00:00.000',' Area8', 'Name2', 8, 5),
('2015-02-24 00:00:00.000',' Area5', 'Name2', 7, 1),
('2015-02-17 00:00:00.000',' Area30', 'Name2', 10, 1),
('2015-01-31 00:00:00.000',' Area23', 'Name1', 9, 6),
('2015-01-23 00:00:00.000',' Area8', 'Name2', 8, 1),
('2015-01-10 00:00:00.000',' Area29', 'Name1', 7, 4),
('2014-12-26 00:00:00.000',' Area24', 'Name2', 10, 5),
('2014-12-13 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 9, 2),
('2014-11-15 00:00:00.000',' Area6', 'Name1', 8, 8),
('2014-10-25 00:00:00.000',' Area7', 'Name1', 7, 6),
('2014-05-24 00:00:00.000',' Area10', 'Name1', 10, 1),
('2014-05-05 00:00:00.000',' Area10', 'Name1', 9, 1),
('2014-04-21 00:00:00.000',' Area7', 'Name1', 8, 2),
('2013-12-26 00:00:00.000',' Area27', 'Name1', 7, 4),
('2013-12-03 00:00:00.000',' Area25', 'Name1', 10, 2),
('2013-11-14 00:00:00.000',' Area18', 'Name1', 9, 4),
('2013-10-23 00:00:00.000',' Area11', 'Name1', 8, 3),
('2013-06-26 00:00:00.000',' Area32', 'Name2', 7, 4),
('2013-06-14 00:00:00.000',' Area1', 'Name2', 10, 6),
('2013-05-18 00:00:00.000',' Area2', 'Name2', 9, 5),
('2013-03-30 00:00:00.000',' Area12', 'Name2', 8, 9),
('2013-02-25 00:00:00.000',' Area22', 'Name1', 7, 1),
('2013-01-08 00:00:00.000',' Area7', 'Name1', 10, 1)

;
```

details details details
details details details
details details details
details details details
details details details

Comment: which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Upvoted because of the care put into making easier to answer the question.  Question of my own... when you say "3 records before the current date", current date means today, or does it mean @Date?

Comment: Also, your desired result has multiple columns that are not provided in the source.  With aggregates, the additional columns may change the logic some.  Can you update the post to provide data for all the fields in your desired result?

Comment: SQL Server 2016. Current date is based on records returned by  `with CurrentRows as` or in this specific example @Date

Comment: Never mind, I see it's @Date

Comment: Why 3 records?  Is that always the fixed range of your previous sum or is that just for this specific data?

Comment: @WesH - site won't let me just edit with more code. The sqlfiddle contains the source table data. 3 is just arbitrary number, I want to say - sum [Issue] for previous n records in descending date order before `@Date`

Comment: can you clearly state what your intention is? the query can be simplified if explained well.

Comment: I compiling stats within a single table based on data before a set date. Most of the derived fields are based on all historic data which can be 100's of records but in this case I only need to collate data based on previous 3 records. Rather than create a new cte for just previous 3 records can I do it within the existing join?

Comment: In the Table Data, you have the product name and area name columns switched

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. I've fixed it in the SQLfiddle and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the window functions in SQL 2016, specifically the OVER clause with the ROWS BETWEEN clause.

Here is a attempt at it.  Its hard to ensure the syntax is correct without the table schema.  I also don't know the name of the column you are sum so I just called it ColumnD based on the spreadsheet source you provided.  I don't think you'll need the join if you are just aggregating over the single table.

DECLARE @Date DATETIME;

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, PreviousSum = SUM(ColumnD) OVER(PARTITION BY AreaName ORDER BY QDate DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 3 PRECEDING)
FROM Control C
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE QDate = @Date
```

Comment: I don't think Wes looked at the table DDL or source data that was posted (not sure of edits).

Answer (score 0):

I turned your query into a CTE and applied Wes' logic, adjusting for the schema, getting rows between 3 and 1 instead of 1 and 3, and sorting by QDate not descending. Nice call Wes with the ROWS between as I was not aware of that option for windowed functions.

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '2018-01-01';


with CurrentRows as
(
    SELECT
        QDate,
        AreaName,
        ProductName,
        PType,
        Issue
    from @Control c
),

cte AS (
select cr.*
    , ProductCountArea = sum(case when c.AreaName = cr.AreaName then 1 else 0 end)
    , ProductMatchArea = sum(case when c.Issue = 1 and c.AreaName = cr.AreaName then 1 else 0 end)
    --, Previous3Sum = sum(?) -- <-- New field here?
from CurrentRows cr
join @Control c on c.QDate < cr.QDate and c.ProductName = cr.ProductName
group by cr.QDate
    , cr.ProductName
    , cr.AreaName
    , cr.PType
    , cr.Issue)

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *, PreviousSum = SUM(PType) OVER(PARTITION BY AreaName ORDER BY QDate ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM cte C
) tbl
WHERE QDate = @Date
ORDER BY AreaName,QDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of a better way to do this after some inspiration from here. If I apply a dense_rank group, say

`dense_rank() over(partition by c.AreaName order by c.QDate desc) as GroupIncrement`

The last 3 records before the current record would then be `between current.GroupIncrement + 1 and Gcurrent.GroupIncrement + 3`

The only assumption is that dense_rank needs to ensure the grouping does not produce ties.

It's also much faster for my specific usage.

**Example query:**

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '2018-01-01';

with CurrentRows as
(
    select *
    , dense_rank() over(partition by c.AreaName order by c.QDate desc) as GroupIncrement
    from Control c    
)

select cr.*
    , ProductCountArea = sum(case when c.AreaName = cr.AreaName then 1 else 0 end)
    , ProductMatchArea = sum(case when c.Issue = 1 and c.AreaName = cr.AreaName then 1 else 0 end)
    , Previous3Sum = sum(case when c.AreaName = cr.AreaName 
                  and c.GroupIncrement between (cr.GroupIncrement + 1) 
                  and (cr.GroupIncrement + 3) then c.Issue else 0 end)
from CurrentRows cr
join CurrentRows c on c.QDate < cr.QDate and c.ProductName = cr.ProductName
where cr.QDate = @Date
group by cr.QDate
    , cr.ProductName
    , cr.AreaName
    , cr.PType
    , cr.Issue
    , cr.GroupIncrement
order by cr.AreaName
```